# How can i achieve a vlookup excel like functionality in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

In Billing Roster - SOW.xlsx I have new column data one is named as SOW and other is named SOW Description (Match value for SOW).
And now when i open ACFC_Resource_Allocation.xlsx excel and for an example if select a value in D2 (SOW) cell from the dropdown i should get a matching value into E2 cell after the selection from dropdown.

I only have an idea than a vlookup from Excel like below should solve my case. Not sure how to achieve in python.
=VLOOKUP(D2,'[Billing Roster - SOW.xlsx]SOW List'!$A$1:$B$14,1,FALSE)

Tried below code

```
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.styles import *
import webbrowser
import pandas
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation


# Read all Excels into pandas dataframes
sowexcel = pandas.read_excel('Billing Roster - SOW.xlsx')

#Load the existing Resource Allocation Excel
wb = load_workbook('ACFC_Resource_Allocation.xlsx')
allocationsheet = wb.active

def load():
   
    maxrow = allocationsheet.max_row
   
    sow_list = sowexcel['SOW #'].tolist()
    column_sow = ','.join(sow_list)
    validator_sow = DataValidation(type='list', formula1='"{}"'.format(column_sow), allow_blank=True)
    allocationsheet.add_data_validation(validator_sow)
    validator_sow.add('D2:D%s' %maxrow)
   
   
    # save the file
    wb.save('ACFC_Resource_Allocation.xlsx')
    wb.close()


# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    load()
    file_open = webbrowser.open('ACFC_Resource_Allocation.xlsx')
```

Comment: You want the `merge` function

Comment: Thanks Daniel but merge alone wont solve my problem. I will select the value under D2 cell from the drop down after my python code executes and the Excel opens up. If my problem was not defined well let me know.

Comment: Any solutions please